# Nvidia GPU issue on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gpu

I've been trying for a while to configure my gpu for my arch install (gtx 960m), using the nvidia drivers, but i can't make it work. My Xorg.conf is a followed :

```
Section "Device
     Identifier   "nvidia"
     Driver       "nvidia"
     BusID        "PCI:1:0:0"
     Option       "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
     VendorName   "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection
```

The output of

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
```

is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 530
        Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Those seems right to me, so i don't know what i've forgotten, maybe you could help!

Comment: What happens when you try to use the NVidia GPU? Is the `nvidia` kernel module loaded?

Answer (score 1):

For me nvidia worked with arch Linux by simple install

```
pacman -S nvidia nvidia-utils nvidia-settings xorg-server-devel opencl-nvidia
```

It auto blacklists nouveau.